# Which are the latest CUDA and cudnn versions compatible with tensorflow 1.15 gpu? I can't find it in tensorflow website

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to set up my system for gpu computing for training deep learning models. The tensorflow version required is 1.15 gpu. I would like to know which version of CUDA and CUDnn i have to install in my system?

Comment: Check the nvidia webset: https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/tensorflow-release-notes/rel_20-03.html#rel_20-03. `CUDA 10.2` is needed for tensorflow>=1.15.0

Answer (score 2):

From the official TF documentation.

For TF >=1.13, CUDA 10. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#install_cuda_with_apt)

For TF>= 2.1, CUDA 10.1. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements)

And, CuDNN will be same for both, CuDNN >= 7.6. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements)

Answer (score 0):

I found "TF 1.15 was compiled against CUDA 10.0" [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/35926). cuDNN 7.6.4 seems to fit this following [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive)